# Exclude files from sync based on filename and/or filename extension in online file storage service

Tags: dropbox, cloud-storage, onedrive, google-drive, sugarsync

Is there an online file storage service (like DropBox, Google Drive, Skydrive) where it is possible to exclude files from sync based on filename and/or filename extension?

Comment: sugersync does apparently, as does spideroak, and there is a thirdparty tool called dropboxfilter for dropbox

Comment: @Paul: Perhaps your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

SpiderOak. https://spideroak.com/manual/sync
By the way, the data on SpiderOak is automatically and transparently encrypted.